# Disable window scrolling when focusing on a form on the ipad

Tags: jquery, html, ios, forms, ipad

I'm making a simple site that will be run from a kiosk app on the ipad, in it is a donate form but when clicking inside the form it slides the form over to center it with the pop up key board and when closing the key board it doesn't slide it back. How can I either prevent that from happening or set it to slide the page back over when the user blurs the input.

Here is what happens when focusing an input

[image: form slides over]

Here is what happens when you close the keyboard

[image: it stays when you close it]

That darker blue is supposed to be all the way to the right of the screen

Comment: Can you post some code or screenshots?

Comment: I added some photos so you can see what I'm talking about